# Getting ListBuckets Method in AWS using S3 API with react?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am retrieving `ListBuckets` method using S3 Api . This is my react code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
export default class Listbuckets extends Component {

 handleClick = () => {
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk')
    // Set the region 
    AWS.config.update({
        region: "ap-south-1"
       });

    // Create S3 service object
 var s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});

    var params = {};
     s3.listBuckets(params, function(err, data) {
       if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
       else   
       {  
        console.log(data);
      }       // successful response

     });
}
render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
          <h1>This is the stats.</h1>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Me</button>
        </div>
    )
  }
 }
```

This is the `CORS` configuration that i enabled for all my buckets.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

But when i run this in react in am getting error like this

```
xhr.js:83 OPTIONS https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/ 403 (Forbidden)
Failed to load https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
Error: Network Failure
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (xhr.js:52) "NetworkingError: Network Failure
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:76976:34)"
```

When i run the same code in node.js it is showing me correct reponse. I dont know what i am missing in my react code. Here is my node.js code

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Set the region 
AWS.config.update({
    region: "ap-south-1"
   });

// Create S3 service object
s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});

var params = {};
 s3.listBuckets(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else   
   {    
       console.log(data)
    //    console.log(data.Buckets.map(x => x.Name))
  }       // successful respons

 });
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: i think you use wrong region

Comment: I double checked in my s3 console where my region is `asia pacifiic(mumbai)`. Which is `ap-south-1`

Answer (score 0):

The `ListBuckets` method of s3 doesnot support cors. This is open issue [in github](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1939)